# How to generate an HTML view in App Script from a Google Sheet

Tags: html, templates, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a client that uses Google forms to take orders and wants to be able to turn the resulting Sheet into a document of Packing Slips. Being a python person I am currently taking her .tsv and making nice HTML printable docs but want to be able to make a plug-in for her so that on any Sheet of this type she can click "Make Packing Slips" and it either opens a new tab with generated HTML (I'm ok using googles templating) or maybe even convert the HTML into a PDF and save it to her drive? Either way I'd rather design the document all in HTML and CSS rather than trying to make a google doc if at all possible. Is the feasible? Any starting points? Thanks!

Comment: It can be done.  It is feasible.  You can convert the HTML to a PDF.  You'll need to save the template somewhere.  You could save it to a text file if you don't want to use Google Docs.  The starting point is creating a custom menu item.  You can assign a script to an image, and make the image look like a button.

Comment: @SandyGood thanks for a starting point! So would this script be tied to each individual script? Or is it something universal I can have show up on all sheets? And can I have the script just open a templeted HTML doc in a new tab or something? I didn't know if that had to be some sort of Google app or something. Thanks again! Super new to App Script!

Comment: If you want a new browser tab to open, that can only be done from HTML.  A custom menu or a message box isn't HTML.  So, you would need a sidebar or a dialog box.  If you have multiple users, and want to distribute code to all of them, then an "Add-on" is maybe your best option.  Each user would need to install the Add-on.   You can share a spreadsheet file that a user would then make a copy of, but then they have access to the code.  If you don't care about that, then that is an option.  In any case the user will need to authorize access to their account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about Google App Script => https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

Then these Links should suffice

1. [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)
2. Google Container-bound Scripts for Google App Script (Can not post link for this due to low reputation)